# WPF: How do I handle mouse click on a Listview inside of a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, button

I have a listview for displaying a table inside of a button. I have a click event assigned to the button, but when the user clicks on the list view, a row is selected on the list view and the mouse click is never bubbled up to the button.

I'm stuck at this point, and need a way to solve this. All the examples I've seen online are for placing a button inside the listview. How do I make this work?

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Can you call the `Button.Click` EventHandler from an EventHandler for `ListView.OnMouseDown` (or `OnMouseUp`) ?

Comment: Add some code/ what you already tried

Comment: Do you want the selection? Why do you make it so complicated for the user? WPF allows a lot more and some things it allows, should not be done. One thing is, to have a list view in a button ... if find this rather confusing. So if you don't need the selection inside the list box, why not just use a Grid with some textblocks?

Comment: The list view is in a user control, so it's doesn't know it's inside a button. I suppose I could expose a click event on the user control and trigger it from a selectionchanged handler.

Comment: Good point dowhilefor. I'm fairly new to WPF. Took me a while to get the listview working in my user control. When I created it, I hadn't intended on putting it inside a button.

I can recreate it as a grid, and I may have to go that route, behind schedule already, so I'm hoping for a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false` on your `ListView`.  Since it is a control that normally processes click events, doing this will have it ignore them.

Comment: This solution is dangerous, i read that a couple of times, and it doesn't lead to the expected result. The user can still use the tab key, to focus the list view, and can still navigate and select inside it. I would advise not to use a listview at all, if most of its functionality is not desired.

Comment: And I would agree to not use the `ListView` at all. Do you have links to where you've read that? I've used this in the past and never ran into any issues with it. And since he's only interested in the clicking (AFAIK), this should be adequate.

Comment: LOL my mind always changes the case of this property and makes me rethink what I am testing here... and if I really want that visible. :)

Comment: This might actually work, since it's on a touch screen kiosk, no keyboard attached.

Comment: I might have mis worded that. I read it in some answers as a perfect valid solution, but some stumble into the issue with the keyboard later on and finding themselfs in the situation to find another solution. I just wanted to point out, that the keyboard still can access the control. But if it is for a kiosk application, its suitable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the items to be selectable in the first place, you could make the List View unable to receive Focus.  Just set the [Focusable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx) property to `false`.

With the List View unable to receive focus, then I would expect the mouse event to bubble up to the button.

Comment: Darn, it was the closest thing I could think of.